# Python AWS Lambda Function ""errorMessage": "'function' object has no attribute 'loads'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm getting "errorMessage": "'function' object has no attribute 'loads'" but loads is part of urllib3. Also if you have any recommendations on how to write this better please let me know.

```
import os
import json
import urllib3
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    def json(get_data):
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        with open("FILE_NAME.json", "rb") as f:
            s3.upload_fileobj(get_data,f, "<bucket_name", None)
    
    class GetToken:
        def __init__(self, API_TOKEN, URL, MY_HEADERS):
            self.token = API_TOKEN
            self.url = URL
            self.headers = MY_HEADERS
        def data(self):
            http = urllib3.PoolManager()
            response = http.request('GET', self.url, headers=self.headers)
            if(response.status == 200):
                get_json = json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
            elif(response.status !=200):
                print("Result not found")
            return get_json

    def members():
        access_results = access()
        base_token = access_results[0]
        base_url = access_results[1]
        base_headers = access_results[2]
        member_url = base_url + 'members'
        post_parameters = GetToken(base_token,member_url,base_headers)
        members_json = post_parameters.data()
        return json(members_json)

    def access():
        clubhouse_token = os.environ.get('CLUBHOUSE_API_TOKEN')
        clubhouse_url = 'https://api.clubhouse.io/api/v3/'
        my_headers = {'Clubhouse-Token': clubhouse_token, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        return clubhouse_token,clubhouse_url,my_headers
    
    return members()
```

Answer (score 1):

despite having a global `import json`, you also have a `def json` in closure scope (a nested function)

lookup in python is Locals, Closure, Globals, Builtins -- and so the closure-scoped function has higher precedence

rename that local `def json` to something else and it should fix your problem